# How to throw 404 from bean in jsf

Tags: jsf-2, http-response-codes

I need to throw 404 and take visitor to a specific page. I am trying with following code:

```
            FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();                
            externalContext.setResponseStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            externalContext.setResponseHeader(Common.LOCATION, "browse_by_category.xhtml?category=CATEGORY_ALL");
            facesContext.responseComplete();
```

404 happens but redirection to the browse_by_category.xhtml page does not happen.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your comment please try this:

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();                
        externalContext.setResponseStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        //externalContext.setResponseHeader(Common.LOCATION, "browse_by_category.xhtml?category=CATEGORY_ALL");
        externalContext.dispatch("browse_by_category.xhtml");
        facesContext.responseComplete();
```

Comment: Yes this did work. Just wanted to confirm that will 404 actually be returned with DISPATCH?

Comment: Yes, you can verify with chrome console

Comment: If It work, please consider to accept answer, it would be appreciated, tnx