# Write 404 on ViewScop and display error file without redirect in JAVA JSF

Tags: java, error-handling, jsf-2.2, view-scope

How do I throw an error **`404`** if the ID was not found without sending a **`302`** redirect.

In my ViewScop I do a select and would like to return an error **`404`** with showing the content of the **`404`** error page (`404.xhtml`).

I tried the following which gives me justs a **`302`** redirect to the `404.xhtml`:

```java
@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    data = service.select(id.getValue());
    if (data == null) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.getExternalContext().setResponseStatus(404);
        context.responseComplete();
        try {
            context.getExternalContext().redirect("/404.xhtml");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Actually if I comment the redirect out, I get the correct error code, but still the called `xhtml` file gets rendered.

**What is the best approach here?** *There are a lot of answers in SO but I didn't find one which was working for me.*

---

**EDIT:** Here some other answers from SO, which was suggested by [@Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969794/write-404-on-viewscop-and-display-error-file-without-redirect-in-java-jsf#comment88935952_50969794) where with I found the correct answer:

- [How to "throw" JSF2 404 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901710/)  - just set's the 404 without showing the content of the 404 page.
- [How to send a person to a 404 page if f:viewParam / converter returns null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796497/) - similar answer from 
  [@BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc), again doesn't show the 404 page which I defined in the `web.xml`.
- [How to throw 404 from bean in jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634441/) - **That is accurately what I was looking for!**

Comment: Could you please add the answers you found here on SO and explain how they could not solve your problem so that no work is unneccesarily redone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to [@Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50969794/write-404-on-viewscop-and-display-error-file-without-redirect-in-java-jsf#comment88935952_50969794) I searched again and found the correct answer: [How to throw 404 from bean in jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634441/) !

The solution is to use [**`.dispatch()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#dispatch-java.lang.String-) on an [`ExternalContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html).

> **dispatch**
>
> `public abstract void dispatch(String path) throws IOException`
>
> Dispatch a request to the specified resource to create output for this
>   response.
>
> *Servlet*: This must be accomplished by calling the
>   `javax.servlet.ServletContext` method `getRequestDispatcher(path)`, and
>   calling the `forward()` method on the resulting object.
>
> If the call to `getRequestDisatcher(path)` returns `null`, send
>   `aServletResponse SC_NOT_FOUND` error code.
>
> **Parameters**: 
>   path - Context relative path to the specified resource, which must start  with a slash ("/") character
>
> **Throws**: 
>       `FacesException` - thrown if a ServletException occurs 
>       `IOException` - if an input/output error occurs

So my solution looks like that now:

```java
@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    data = service.select(id.getValue());
    if (data == null) {
        try {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
            externalContext.setResponseStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            externalContext.dispatch("/404.xhtml");
            context.responseComplete();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```